# How to not calculate the length of string if the input is a float number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Program is to calculate the length of string using len() method.String is taken as input from the user using input() function.Now the question is if the input is int instead of string it will not calculate the length.But i was not able to do the second part i.e if the input is float instead of string.
what can i do inside the code or what library functions can i use?

```
def strlength(string):
    len1=len(string)
    return len1

len1=input("Enter any string:")

if len1.isdigit()==True:
    print("Integers cannot have length !")
elif bool(len1.find("."))==True:
    print("Float numbers cannot have length !")
else:
    print(strlength(len1))
```

Comment: `input` always returns a string, as it seems you know, but why isn't `1234` a valid string containing 4 characters that are digits? Also, why wouldn't `hello...` be a valid string of 8 characters? Also note that `str.find` returns `-1` if the substring/character isn't found, and `bool(-1)` is always `True` in that case - the only case it's going to be false is when it's 0 which is actually when it's found as the first character which isn't what you want... you need to explicitly check against `-1` there...

Comment: what about ```isinstance(mynumber, float)```? It's helpful to your case? Also you can use ```Decimal``` class to generify numbers, it's best way IMHO. Also you can sanitize user input with ```input.replace(".", "")``` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It only accepts only non integer and no float type inputs to return correct length.

```
def strlength(string):
    if string.isdigit():
        return False
    if string.find('.') > 0:
        a, b = string.split('.') 
        if a.isdigit() and b.isdigit():
            return False 
    if  type(string) == str :
            return len(string)


length = strlength(input("Enter any string:"))
if (length):
    print("The length of the string is ", length)
else:
    print("The input was an integer or a float.")
```

This should help your cause.

Comment: It won't help as `input()` always returns a `str` in Python 3.x

Comment: Agreed, had missed to add the clause for `elif`

Comment: In Python 3.x, you'll never hit any other conditions as the `if type(string) == str` is always going to be true... (and a sidenote, it's generally best written as `if isinstance(string, str)` unless you want some really explicit (and mostly unlikely strict type checking)

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding, he need to get the length of any float type numbers, correct?

Comment: From my understanding - they only need to get the length of an input that can't be a float/int

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take your problem the other way. As I understand it, your problem is when the input is a number, but the input method always give a string. So first step try to convert the *input* value to a number, if it works do nothing but if it throw a ValueError you have a string so you can get the length.

```
def strlength(string):
    """"""
    try:
        float(string)
        print('The input was a number')
        return None
    except ValueError:
        return len(string)


len1 = input('Enter any string:')
print(strlength(len1))
```

But it doesn't work if the input is a number following by a string such as '*15.2toto*'. If you really don't want to take into account any number in a string you should then look to the *sub* method of the *re* module to remove any numbers using a regex.